# ObjectAnimator Choppy Scrolling

Tags: java, android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, objectanimator

I have an activity that contains a HorizontalScrollView.  The HorizontalScrollView has three fragments in it.  On a button click the scrollview will scroll from left to right or vice versa.  I am accomplishing this like so...

```
    private void scrollTo(int x) {
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScroller, "scrollX", x);
        animator.setDuration(800);
        animator.start();
    }
```

On my Nexus 7 (1st Gen) it scrolls smoothly, but on my Moto G phone, it is super choppy.  Any ideas how I could correct this?

---

**Update**

I figured out that if I changed the background drawable on one of the fragments the problem will go away.  The image I was using is very plain, so I never thought that would be the problem.  The image I replaced it with is much larger in size, but is just a repeated pattern.

I set the background with a .png like this

```
android:background="@drawable/my_background"
```

Old Background (non working)
[image]

New Background (works)
[image]

Comment: What are you drawing? It's possibly due to some very complex drawing in your scrollview. Try to remove all unnecessary views (perhaps replacing them with plain views with a background), and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being my background image.  I used a 9 patch tool located [here](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html) to generate different size images and all is well now.

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html